# Where was it said? Don't post only answers which point to your own blog or webs site

Tags: discussion

I know I saw answers to some question, in which one responder was told that he always referred questioners to his own blog or website, and that it was OK to do it sometimes... but that he should stop choosing to answer only questions for which his external site was the answer.

I didn't bookmark it, and I can't seem to find it again.

Comment: I recall [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/closure-other-action-regarding-qubrix-brain-twister-question) on the "Qubrix Brain Twister", which also involved NSFW issues.

Comment: An interesting issue, but not the post I was trying to find... in which the dictum, as I saw it, was "Don't select only questions for which you have prepared answers on your own site. We don't want you here in that case."

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to

https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion

> #### May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

Comment: Thanks, this will do. There really is an exemplar question out there where people criticized answer for precisely this reason, and I was hoping to recover that... it's not so urgent thanks to the FAQ. And I apologize for not seeing this in the FAQ.